# How to graph two variables onto a US county map in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, graph, maps, fips

df1:

```
score1   score2 FIPS
0.1230    4     1001
0.4503    1     2001
0.5642    0     4001
0.2011    3     5001
0.2012    2     6001
0.1093    0     8001
0.3422    10    1005
0.1033    3     17001
0.2432    30    19001
0.1002    7     1017
```

I would like to shade each county in the united states based on a weight by `score1`, I would then like to make translucent circles around counties based on `score2`. How can I do this?

Output: 
[image]

Comment: I was thinking add = TRUE in  `par` but I think @johan-rosa has your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I did what I think you want as follows.

1. I got the USA shapefiles from [this url](https://tapiquen-sig.jimdofree.com/app/download/5501619359/USA_States.rar?t=1455822096).
2. you need the `sf`, `dplyr`, and `ggplot2` packages.

Since you did not provide a reproducible example of your data, I had to simulate the `score1` and `score2` variables.

```
# packages --------------------------------------
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Import shape files
# (You have to unpack the zip with the shape files)
usa_map <- read_sf("USA_States.shx")

# Adding the variables you need. 
# In your case you can left_join your variables 

usa_map <- usa_map %>% 
    mutate(
        score1 = sample(1:1000, 51),
        score2 = sample(1:500, 51)
    ) %>% 
    filter(!STATE_NAME %in% c("Alaska", "Hawaii"))

# Use ggplot2 to make the plot
usa_map %>% 
    ggplot() +
    geom_sf(aes(fill = score1)) +
    geom_sf(data = st_centroid(usa_map), aes(size = score2), alpha = 0.4, color = "red") +
    guides(size = FALSE) +
    theme_void()
```

[image]